# Ошибка SQLite3 Python

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

Помогите решить ошибку пожалуйста.
Код:

```
def connect(obj: Union[types.Message, CallbackQuery]):
    user_id = obj.from_user.id
    cursor.execute('SELECT grup FROM Users WHERE id = ?', (user_id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print('none')
    return result


groups = {'СВ-31': 'SV_31', 'СП-31': 'SP_31'}


def fetch_for_group(group_code):
    cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = f'{group_code}__PN_n'")
    row1 = cursor.fetchone()
    return row1[0]


@dp.message_handler(text='ПН')
async def pn(message: types.Message):
    result = connect(message)
    for row in result:
        if row in groups.keys():
            info = fetch_for_group(groups[row])
            await message.answer(info, reply_markup=il_1)
```

Код ошибки:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = f'{group_code}__PN_n'")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'{group_code}__PN_n'": syntax error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы что-то перепутали, когда пытались применить f-строки, не стали разбираться и что-то додумали сами, а теперь удивляетесь, что это не работает:)

https://python-scripts.com/f-strings

```
"SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = f'{group_code}__PN_n'"
```

именно это будет передано в исполнение. group_code не подставится никуда. Это окончательная строка.

Быть может вы имели ввиду это?

```
f"SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = '{group_code}__PN_n'"
```

А вообще - этот способ подвержен страшной уязвимости - SQL-инъекции.

Передавайте параметры правильно, тем более, вы прекрасно знаете, как их передавать, судя по коду вначале:

```
cur.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = ?", (f'{group_code}__PN_n', ))
```

Полезная ссылка: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html